# How to change decimal mark in papaja::apa_print?

Tags: r, internationalization, papaja

I wanted to use `papaja::apa_print()` to make things easier in my report but I need to adjust the output for my language's APA style adaptation. It means displaying leading zeros and setting comma as the decimal mark. It's not a problem with most of `papaja` functions but with `apa_print()` is not that straightforward.

```
library(papaja)
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
anova(model) |> apa_print(decimal.mark = ",", gt1 = TRUE)
```

The options are applied to most of the output but not to p-values and F-ratios (at least in ANOVA). I thought it might apply to all LaTeX parts of the output but eta-squared seems to be OK. I believe it might be a bug. So how do I deal with it? Should I report it as a bug? Part of the output for reference:

```
$estimate
$estimate$Species
[1] "$\\hat{\\eta}^2_G = 0,401$, 90\\% CI $[0,300, 0,485]$"


$statistic
$statistic$Species
[1] "$F(2, 147) = 49.16$, $p < .001$"


$full_result
$full_result$Species
[1] "$F(2, 147) = 49.16$, $p < .001$, $\\hat{\\eta}^2_G = 0,401$, 90\\% CI $[0,300, 0,485]$"


$table
A data.frame with 7 labelled columns:

     term estimate       conf.int statistic df df.residual p.value
1 Species    0,401 [0,300, 0,485]     49.16  2         147  < .001
```

Comment: For anyone interested in this, there is a discussion about this in two issues on the papaja GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/525) and [here](https://github.com/crsh/papaja/issues/506).